# How to send data from one react component to another react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Here I get some data from the 'Order' component and then I want to send this data to Navigate but all I get when using 'props.order_data' in 'Navigate' is undefined. How can I use this data in 'Navigate'?

```
function App(){

  function getData(some){
    console.log(some);
    return(<Navigate order_data= {some}/>);
  }
  return(
    <div>
      <Navigate />
      <Service/>
      <Order onAdd={getData}/>
      <Review />
      <Foot />
  </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `useState` hook to maintain a state. Since you have your `Navigate` and `Order` component in the same Parent `App`.

Do like this

```
 import { useState } from "react";

 function App(){

  const [some, setSome] = useState(null); // Initial some value is null

  function getData(data){
    setSome(data); // This will update some state value
  }
  return(
    <div>
      <Navigate order_data={some}/> 
      <Service/>
      <Order onAdd={getData}/>
      <Review />
      <Foot />
  </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do won't work as the return-value of the `getData` function is passed to the `Order`-component's `onAdd` function.

I would suggest that you create a state for the `order_data` in your App-component and pass the state as a prop to the `Navigate`-element that you are returning. You will need to update the state as soon as you retrieve the data (e.g. in `getData` function).

React will take care of updating the component as soon as the state changes.

See React documentation for more details:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html